# Bugsnag request failed to complete

Tags: android, react-native, build, gradlew, bugsnag

Im using Bugsnag in my React Native project, but I trying run the command:
`./gradlew assembleDevelopmentRelease` and I receive the error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:bugsnagReleaseDevelopment-releaseTask'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Bugsnag request failed to complete
```

[Erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRVKg.png)

Comment: Hi - unfortunately there isn't much detail in that error output. Could you please re-run the build with the `--info` or `--debug` option enabled in order to get some more verbose logging, and send the full output to support@bugsnag.com so that we can take a look?

It would also be really helpful if you could share all of your Bugsnag configuration code for both your JS and Android layers, including both build.gradle files and your AndroidManifest.xml​, to see if we can spot any issues there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add `-keepattributes LineNumberTable,SourceFile` to `proguard-rules.pro`. You can find more information about this [here](https://docs.bugsnag.com/api/android-mapping-upload/).